# Set a List Item Value before Submit on a new form in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I'm using PowerApps to develop against a SharePoint List. I have a Variable that gets set and I want to set a field in a SharePoint list (within PowerApps) with the value of the variable before "SubmitForm()"

Can anyone help me with this?

Bismarck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see an article here with a nice tutorial: [POWER APPS: SET A FIELD VALUE.](https://wonderlaura.com/2018/06/01/powerapps-set-a-field-value/)

You can set the default value to the variable in the **OnSave** property under **SharePointIntegration**.

Example:

```
If(
    SharePointForm1.Mode=New,
    Set(varDefault, User().FullName)
    );
SubmitForm(SharePointForm1)
```

Then in the **Default** property on the field control, put

```
If(IsBlank(varDefault),ThisItem.[FieldName],varDefault)
```

So every time a new item gets created, it takes the default value `User().FullName` when the form gets submitted, but it allows modification on the Edit Form.